# Capturing picture is not working in Android ( Samsung, Lenovo, Lava etc...)

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

This is the code i am using to open the camera app(Pre-installed camera application )

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, BTN1_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

In OnActivityResult method

```
Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                picUri = getImageUri(this, image);
                if (picUri != null) {
                    View view = ((LinearLayout) btn.getParent())
                            .findViewById(1);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bao);
                    byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
                    btnImg1 = Base64.encodeToString(ba, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    BitmapDrawable bdrawable2 = new BitmapDrawable(image);
                    view.setBackgroundDrawable(bdrawable2);
```

Is this having any issues please let me know any kind of suggestions are also welcomed thanks in advance....

If this method is wrong please let me know what i need to do to capture the image in every kind of mobile with out any issue....

(THANKS IN ADVANCE)

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "is not working" means.

Comment: You should get image uri by using `data.getData()`

Comment: @kientux i m using this Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

Comment: @CommonsWare "Not working" means when i call camera intent it is going to camera app after clicking on capture it is directly closing the camera and no data is coming in onActivityResult()

Comment: @kientux instead of using picUri = getImageUri(this, image);  i should use picUri = data.getData(); this is what you are telling?

Comment: yes, that's is the uri of captured image. Then you have to parse the file path from that uri and create bitmap from file path.